How to find openSSL's AES T-table location for cache side channel attack
Let us assume I have a physically-indexed last-level cache, which is shared between the victim and adversary. Both the victim and attacker have their own copy of openSSL library in the caches. Victim has activated the cache randomization technique. The attacker wants to steal the victim's AES key using cache-based side-channel attacks such as prime-probe.
Question - How will an attacker find the victim's target address i.e. the location where the victim's T-table is located? Even if the attacker figures out the eviction set, how will she find the victim's T-table's address?
